Is there a theoretical advantage for market cap weighted index funds over equal weighted index funds?
Hey there:) I’m new to the field and have plenty of questions. Would be happy if any of you can answer any of these:

Is there a theoretical advantage for market cap weighted index funds over equal weighted index funds?
And if so, why does it exist?
Does this advantage mean higher expected returns? Or maybe lower risk?

Thanks!

An index fund, to be an index fund, should be following the mix that makes up the index, or as close to that as it can get. I'm not sure how you could adjust weights and still be an index fund, other than by following a different index.

@keshlam Equal-weight index do exist: https://www.spglobal.com/spdji/en/documents/education/education-equal-weight-indexing.pdf

Yes, there is a theoretical advantage for market cap-weighted index funds over equal-weighted index funds under the Capital Asset Pricing Model (CAPM) and the Modern Portfolio Theory. In this answer, I will loosely demonstrate under these theories why the market cap-weighted index fund is the optimal portfolio of risky assets, and is hence more advantageous than the equal-weighted index fund.
Under these theories, an investor maximizes the expected return given a risk level. The optimal portfolio consists of a mix of a risk-free asset (e.g., Treasury bills) and a portfolio of risky assets (e.g., equities).
Let's now narrow down to optimizing the portfolio of the risky assets, e.g., equities. [*]
Assumptions
The directly relevant assumptions are (the other assumptions also matter; simplifying things here):


Are rational and risk-averse. (Meaning that an investor prefers lower risk given the same expected return.)
Have homogeneous expectations. (All investors agree about the risk and expected return of all assets).
Assume all information is available at the same time to all investors.


The Whole Market is the Optimal Portfolio
Under these assumptions, to maximize the expected return given a risk, or to minimize the risk given an expected return, a portfolio consisting of the whole market, i.e., market cap-weighted index, must be optimal.
Why?
Let's loosely prove this by contradiction. Assume that the stock weights in the market is slightly different from the optimal portfolio, say Stock A is slightly mispriced. Since all investors share the same information, and same investment objective, all investors share the same valuation of Stock A. Then, investors will correct the price of Stock A, until it reaches the point that the weights of stocks in the whole market equal those of the optimal portfolio.
Additional Notes
Hope the above answer helps with understanding the theoretical advantage. In reality, the assumptions aren't all true, but the theories are nonetheless  meaningful guidance. Additionally, more sophisticated theories don't suggest that the whole market is the optimal portfolio of risky assets, but they likely still suggest that market cap-weighted index fund is more advantageous than equal-weight index fund in most cases. In fact, I personally found that the claimed advantages of equal-weighted index funds I've encountered rarely stand up to scrutiny in terms of optimizing for investors.
[*] Here, I take for granted that the optimization of the mix and the portfolio of risky assets can be optimized separately.

Any of the indexes you are likely to find funds that track are going to be market cap weighted.  The Dow Jones Industrial Average is just about the only equal weighted index you'll come across.  There are few if any funds that track that index however.
Mechanically, the biggest advantage of a market weighted index is that it minimizes the need for rebalancing transactions.  Say your index has 3 companies A, B, and C.  In the morning, you buy $10 of each in an equal weighted index.  By the end of the day, you have $11 in A, $10 in B, and $9 in C because A went up and C went down.  In an equal-weighted index, you'd need to sell $1 of A, recognizing a taxable gain that would potentially need to get distributed to people that own the fund.  If you had a market-cap weighted fund, you wouldn't need to do any rebalancing-- the market caps of A and C changed by exactly the same percentage that their value in your holdings changed.  Over time, not having to constantly rebalance leads to lower fees (and lower tracking errors) and not having to constantly recognize gains and losses makes holding funds more tax efficient for investors.
